# How can I use a var in a C# for loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop

Im trying to learn programming and start from the basics but cannot figure it out.
Im trying to use my user input var amount and get it the user input text value and use it in the for loop.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("URL To ICMP: ");
        var url = System.Console.ReadLine();

        System.Console.WriteLine("How many times do you want to ping " + url + "?");
        var amount = System.Console.ReadLine();

        Ping myPing = new Ping();
        PingReply reply = myPing.Send(url);

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i = i + 1)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine();
            if (i = amount)
            {
                break;
                System.Console.WriteLine("\nFinished ICMP");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `Ping` part go inside the for loop? You want to repeat that action a particular amount of times after all

Comment: Shouldn't `if(i=amount)` be `if(i==amount)`? With one `=`, you won't loop much, as you'll reach the exit condition during the first iteration. But I feel like your code won't event compile, as you try to compare an `int` (`i`) with a `string` (`amount`)

Comment: The whole if (i == amount) {...} is pointless. 'i' will never equal 'amount' because the loop only runs while 'i' is less than 'amount'.

Comment: also: `amount` is a `string`, and `i` is an `int`; they will never be equal; consider `int.Parse` / `int.TryParse` on the `string`

Comment: As a side-note, if you're developing on a windows server: There was a time when debugging `Ping` could crash your server. Not sure if that bug is still around, but I found out the hard way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code. To answer your question though first, you need to move your ping down into your loop. The rest I will note with comments:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("URL To ICMP: ");
        var url = System.Console.ReadLine();

        // Use String.Format instead of concatenation.
        System.Console.WriteLine(String.Format("How many times do you want to ping {0}?", url));
        var amount = System.Console.ReadLine();
        int count;
        if(!int.TryParse(amount, out count)) // You should attempt to convert to integer.
        {
            // If invalid, notify user and return.
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid number!");
            return;
        }
        Ping myPing = new Ping();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) // use the `count` variable.
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Pinging host: {0}...", url));
            // You can use PingReply below to write the response
            // If you do not plan to use that, I would omit the set here
            // and just use `myPing.Send(url);`
            PingReply reply = myPing.Send(url);

            // This next section you do not need as the loop will automatically break 
            // after the set number of iterations.
            // if (i = amount) // this should actually be  `==` instead of `=`
            // {
            //     break;
            //     System.Console.WriteLine("\nFinished ICMP");
            // }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: String *interpolation* can be even better (more readable) than `Format`, e.g. `$"How many times do you want to ping {url}?"`

Comment: whats the most amount of pings I could use in this?

Comment: As an `integer` (`Int32`), the max value is `2147483647`.